# Aligning table header text and a checkbox all on one line and left-justified

Tags: css, reactjs, css-tables, react-table

I am using React for an automobile web app.

I am using a table library called React-Talbe to build a dynamic table.

To display HTML in a table header, I need to do this:

```
Header: () => (<div style={{ margin: 0, width: 250 }}><span>Vehicle Choices</span><span> *Include Foreign <input type="checkbox" name="includeForeignAutos" /></span></div>),
```

But when it renders to the webpage, it looks bad like this:

```
   Vehicle Choices *Include    
   Foreign
             [ ]
```

I am trying to get it to line up to the left and all on one line, like this:

```
   Vehicle Choices  *Include Foreign [ ]
```

This is what the rendered HTML looks like:

```
<th colspan="8" role="columnheader">
    <div>
       <span>
          <div style="margin: 0px; width: 250px;">
             <span>Vehicle Choices</span>
             <span> 
                " *Include Foreign "
                <input type="checkbox" name="includeForeignAutos">
             </span>
          </div>
       </span>
    </div>
</th>
```

Is there a way to use inline style tags to make sure it is all and one line and justified to the left of the table header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have width set as **250px** and it requires more width to be in the same line. Width is less that is why it is not coming in same line.

Comment: Oh I see, I will trying making it 300 and see what that does